# Examples of production-heavy usage of javascript web-workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

A year ago I've already asked a question about [webworkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125487/who-has-proposed-web-workers), but it was closed as not constructive.
OK, let me try another way. The question is - what big (well may be not so big, but real, production-ready) web projects are using web-workers? Which examples can you name?

Comment: you can wait for real applications or wait for it dies :P

Comment: @Ghostoy i'm just checking out my hypothetis, which is - current thread implementation in javascript don't fit for any practical purposes.